# Replace all relative times with local times

Tags: script

This script replaces all relative time with local time by parsing the Zulu time from the title element of the span elements.

**The replacement happens only after hovering over the date.**

To view the source of the script: https://gist.github.com/dannyhajj/8057530

To install the script [click here](https://gist.github.com/dannyhajj/8057530/raw/showlocaltime.user.js).

<sup>This script was inspired by this question http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7869/is-there-a-way-to-disable-relative-dates-and-times-on-posts-and-comments</sup>